# pythonのスライスとソートすると意図しない出力が出る

Tags: python

pythonのスライスとソートについて質問です。

パターン1の変数aとパターン2の変数dataで同じ出力が出ると思うのですが、
出力が意図していないものなので、なぜこのような出力なのかご教授お願いしたいです。

パターン2でスライスしたものを.sort()すると、スライスしたものがソートされておりません。

パターン1

```py
data = [6,10,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a = data[1:8:2]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

出力

```
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

パターン2

```py
data = [6,10,3,4,5,6,7,8]
data[1:8:2].sort()
print(data)
```

出力

```
[6, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: タイトルに内包表記とありますが質問内容とは関係ないと思います。

Comment: `data[1:8:2]`は リスト内包表記(list comprehension) ではなく [スライス表記(slicing)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) と呼ばれる記法ですね。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。data[1:8:2].sort()が内包表現では・・・？と思ったのでこのタイトルにしておりました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。タイトル変更しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スライス結果のコピーをソートしているからです。

書かれているコード

```
data[1:8:2].sort()
print(data)
```

これは以下と同義です

```
a = data[1:8:2]
a.sort()
print(data)
```

`data[1:8:2]` はスライス結果を返しますが、 `data` そのものは変更しません。

Answer (score 2):

スライスは元のdataとは別の新しいインスタンスになります。
sort()は新しいインスタンスに作用するため、dataそのものは何も変わりません。